# @ngx/store/update-reducers modifies state of my application undesirably

Tags: angular, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, ngrx

In my application developed in **Angular**, I use the services of **Firebase Authentication** to authenticate, at the moment of the login of my application the states are changed in the correct way, keeping all the state of the form as I need.

When I log in I noticed in **Redux DevTools** that the state of my application has the `"auth"` authentication status so I can access data from the authenticated user.

When I navigate to any other page on my system the `"auth"` auth status disappears after an event that occurs called `"@ngrx/store/update-reducers"` and there I can no longer have authentication status information on my system.

Why might this be happening? Why is `"@ngrx/store/update-reducers"` being invoked?

I have a file that is in a `"store"` folder inside the `"src/app"` tree.
In this file I have all the reducers I create in the root module `"app.module"`.

**index.ts:**

```
import { ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Params } from '@angular/router';

import * as fromRouter from '@ngrx/router-store';
import * as fromAuth from '../reducers/auth.reducer';
import * as fromMessenger from '../reducers/messenger.reducer';

export interface RouterStateUrl {
    url: string;
    queryParams: Params;
    params: Params;
}

export interface StateApp {
    auth: fromAuth.AuthState;
    router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
    messenger: fromMessenger.MessengerState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<StateApp> = {
    auth: fromAuth.reducer,
    router: fromRouter.routerReducer,
    messenger: fromMessenger.reducer
};

export const getMessengerState = createFeatureSelector<fromMessenger.MessengerState>('messenger');
export const getAuthState = createFeatureSelector<fromAuth.AuthState>('auth');

export const getRouterState = createFeatureSelector
    <fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>>
    ('router');

export class CustomSerializer
    implements fromRouter.RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
    serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {

        const { url } = routerState;
        const { queryParams } = routerState.root;

        let state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = routerState.root;

        while (state.firstChild) {
            state = state.firstChild;
        }

        const { params } = state;

        return { url, queryParams, params };
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { reducers, CustomSerializer } from './store/reducers';
import { effects } from './store/effects';

 StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),
```

The `"messenger"` state and the others are maintained, the only state that is not maintained when I navigate from one page to the other is the `"auth"` state.

Answer (score 2):

The `@ngrx/store/update-reducers` is dispatched where modules are registered. 
This is hard to "solve" without seeing the full code, be sure that you don't update your store state directly (the ngrx-store-freeze metareducer could help) and that every reducer is returning state (make sure to have a default case in your reducer's switch statement that simply returns state..

Comment: the `"auth"` status logic is the same as `"messenger"`, the state `"messenger"` is maintained and the `"auth"` status is not maintained ... can this problem be in my `auth.reducer`?

Comment: yes it could be, but as I said before - without the code it's hard to pinpoint the cause of this.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and managed to solve it.

The root cause was StoreModule.forRoot(...) was being called again when I loaded another module. I had my StoreModule.forRoot in a module where I store my core code, CoreModule.
CoreModule was only meant to be imported once, but I created a new Module and when I navigated to that module it was importing CoreModule and calling StoreModule.forRoot(...) again which cleared the store.